# Global alignment method for decimal sequence and distance

Tags: algorithm, bioinformatics, data-analysis, sequence-alignment

**Hi**
I'd like to align two decimal sequences to calculate the distance between them and be able to perform an sum of them
 for example let S1 and S2 be these two sequences : 
*S1*=[0.568,0.469,0.3658,0.31667]
*S2*=[0.64918,1.16]
This is only a random example to show you my point 
I'm currently trying to use the [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) to perform that but it's really hard to translate that one to numerical and now i'm trying with [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) 
**But** is there an algorithm designed for this kind of problem which is numerical data only ?

Comment: it's not at all clear how an alignment of your two sequences should look like. In general the algorithm itself can be applied to any kind of sequences - you just have to define a sensible distance metric.

Comment: As cel says, NW should work find for numerical data if you have a suitable distance metric between all numbers (and a way to handle periods and commas, perhaps as gaps or as characters themselves)

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once.

Comment: @m69 I didn't post it twice it's not the same question anymore